# Query Time series data based on Date

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

If I have the below document, I would like to return the same document but with hourly.1 based on the minute inside the date field.

Does anyone know how to dynamically do this? If the date had 0 minute I want the hourly.0 returned. All the way up to the 59th minute.

```
{
        "_id" : "08062017/cpu",
        "date" : ISODate("2018-04-11T02:01:00.000Z"),
        "metadata" : {
                "host" : "localhost",
                "metric" : "cpu"
        },
        "hourly" : {
                "0" : {
                        "total" : 234,
                        "used" : 123
                },
                "1" : {
                        "total" : 234,
                        "used" : 123
                }
        }
}
```

RESULT:

```
   {
        "_id" : "08062017/cpu",
        "date" : ISODate("2018-04-11T02:01:00.000Z"),
        "metadata" : {
                "host" : "localhost",
                "metric" : "cpu"
        },
        "hourly" : {
                "0" : {
                        "total" : 234,
                        "used" : 123
                }

        }
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean here. The point of such a structure is that you write the data for `total` and `used` as time progresses into the document. Typically this is already "accumulated" by using an operator such as `$inc`. Also when you say "by the minute" then it's again not clear but you seem to be thinking these totals can be "broken down" where they cannot. By the look of it the `date` field in this data is probably created at a "set time" of the day as the day itself "rolls over" and a new document is created for that day. This is typically how these structures work.

Comment: More documents shown in the question might make it clearer, but I suspect they all show the same `1am` time which would be the creation time of the document, and nothing to do with where the underlying metrics are recorded. Sort of looks like somebody else wrote the code that creates this, and you're trying to come to understanding it. But you're missing the point of why it was done this way in the first place. If you want "by the minute" you probably need a different data source to this one.

Comment: I added an Edit, All i want is to filter out the hourly nested object. The query should filter out the proper nested object from the minute in the date. This is just an example, my actually code is very complicated so didn't want to copy and paste a big mess here. Lets just make it simple and say there is one document in the collection hardcoded like above. How do i get the Result i provided based on the minute in the date field.

Comment: You did not write the code which wrote the structure initially did you? Because like I said already, you seem to be missing the point. You don;t need to repeat your question, just read what I wrote. You cannot get a "minute" from this. You don't have an answer because you are asking someone to extract something that does not exist.

Comment: I did not write the code, it is an example. Would it help if 
"date":0

Comment: No it won't. Read back my comments a few times and search "mongodb time series" and start seeing how they all say the same thing. There is no "minutes" here.